# Error while try to rename a file name in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is my code:

```
filename_date = strcat('Maayanei_yeshua-IC_',file_date,'.pdf')
filenamepdf = strcat(filename,'.pdf')
rename(['C:\Users\user\Desktop\' filenamepdf],['C:\Users\user\Desktop\' filename_date]);
```

And i get the error:

```
<??? Error using ==> movefile The system cannot find the path specified.>
```

or

```
<??? Undefined function or method 'rename' for input arguments of type 'char'.>
```

I checked hundreds of times and the file is there... i don't know why it can't find it, any help ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that in MATLAB? Why not write a batch script to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
doc rename
```

to discover that `rename` is for working with ftp servers, which you are not doing here.  What you want is the command `movefile`

Use the help window brought up by `helpwin` to look up all the commands you are using.

Also, from the command prompt try

```
dir(['C:\Users\user\Desktop\' filenamepdf])
```

to verify the file you want to move exists.